# How to get a FileField URL witout creating template

Tags: django, filefield

I want to download file from my django site, when click on link.
If i add file url to link, it downloads it, but i do it manually, i want to do it using link.
How to make it, using  without creating a template.

```
<a href="{% url 'material' pk=material.pk %}"> {{ material.title }}</a>
```

```py
def material(request, pk):
   material_by_pk = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=pk)
   return material_by_pk.data.url


class Material(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    data = models.FileField(upload_to=material_url)
```

Everything stores in media directory.

Comment: Have you tried just `material_by_pk.url`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work cause view function creates a template

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{material.data.url}}"> {{ material.title }}</a>
```

It works :)